# Is there any way to have a javascript function fire when I click on some part of an ASP.NET calendar?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

When you click on the numbers of an asp.NET calendar, it calls the server-side function specified by OnSelectionChange. I'd like to be able to click on the space around a number and call a javascript function. Firebug tells me this is what makes up a single "cell" of a calendar (that is, one day):

```
<td class="DayStyle" align="right" style="color:#CEE2ED;border-color:#CEE2ED;border-width:3px;   border-style:solid;width:14%;">
    <a title="July 19" style="color:#CEE2ED" href="javascript:__doPostBack('myCal','4217')">19</a>
</td>
```

That is, I want a function to fire when the user clicks on a td with the class 'DayStyle.' Is there perhaps a jQuery solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily do this:

```
$("#<%= myCal.ClientID %>").find("td.DayStyle").click(function() {
   //Do something
});
```

This would limit the finding to within the calendar.  Are you looking to cause a postback when you click the cell too?

Comment: That was amazingly easy, you're right. I might need to cause a postback a bit later. I was just planning on calling update() on my update panel or submit() on the form. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Actually, there's an issue with this. I didn't specify, but I only want the javascript function to happen if the user does click on something within the td that isn't the number itself. I messed around a bit and tried to just break out of the function if they did click that, but couldn't find a way to do it since the number is just text according to firebug.